# Monte Carlo Simulation probability exercise without loops in R

Tags: r, loops, simulation, probability, montecarlo

I need to do this exercise  in R with Monte Carlo Simulation and without using loops, this is teh reason I'm struggling. This is the exercise: Let Z (n) be the maximum of n observations from a standard normal distribution. Estimate the value n must take for P (Z (n)> 4) = 0.25.

This is all the code I got

```
n = 10000

x = replicate(n, max(rnorm(?)))


prob = (sum(x>=4))/n


prob must be = 0.25
```

Comment: Of course ultimately whatever code it is is going to be using a `for` loop (or maybe, a `while` or even `repeat` loop). Anyway, your code looks basically fine, what's the issue?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to finish the code, I need to find the ? in rnorm(?) which is the number of observations that will lead me to have a probability of 0.25 of getting a numer higher than 4.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267454/problem-with-montecarlo-simulation-normal-distribution

Comment: try for `?=1`; then try for `?=5e4`, then keep searching :)

Comment: That's not very efficient

Comment: Well, so the problem is to search for n. Here is one heuristic: start with n = 1, then n = 2, n = 4, etc, doubling n each time. Eventually you'll find an n which is too big. Now do a bisection search from n/2 to n. What makes this problem hard is that your estimate of `prob` is noisy. You might not be able to find a single value of n -- maybe you should settle for just finding a range of values which are plausible, and try to make the range as small as possible. Good luck and have fun, it's a good problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Problem with MonteCarlo Simulation and Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290213/r-problem-with-montecarlo-simulation-and-normal-distribution)